# How can I update entity in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I need to update entity that I loaded from the datastore. How can I do this with GAE JDO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is explained in the [official "Getting Started" tutorial](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html)'s section on [Using the Datastore with JDO](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html).  This section contain information about updating entities (with the [PersistenceManager](http://db.apache.org/jdo/pm.html)).

Comment: I actually had problem in my code, because I was automatically populating my entities, and I used to access private attributes and I didn't use setter method, so JDO didn't notice changes. I changed my automated tool to use setter methods and it started to work.